# How to use module name aliasing in angular cli?

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

Using standalone webpack, you could use aliasing for module resolving.
something like this inside your webpack.config file, config.resolve block:

```
config.resolve = {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
    alias: {
      'app': 'src/app',
      'common': 'src/common',
       'a_module_name': 'file_path_to_module_name'
    }
  };
```

**How do you use webpack like alias resolution inside angular cli?**

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same issue, do you have any solution for this?

Comment: currently not. Perhaps, you can upvote the question so it receives more attention. I actually moved away from cli, because of this and started using angular 2 webpack starter

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, and according to a discussion at github it looks like they are not going to exposed the webpack config, but I can't find any work around for this

Answer (score 1):

Try using the typescript `compilerOptions` `paths` array inside your **tsconfig.json** file:

The paths array values are **relative** to the `baseUrl`. Here is an example usage:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@app/*": ["app/*"]
  }
}
```